# Information flow when redirecting from HTML to Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have a question regarding the information flow of a simple link.
Let's say I have an HTML that does this:

```
<a href="servlet">Go to Servlet</a>
```

And in that servlet, I have a `doGet`, `doPost`, and a lot of other methods. Where does the information go to at first? Which block will be the first to kick in?

I know servlets shouldn't have all these methods and responsibilities, it's just a piece of code from a book (Professional java for web applications) that will introduce JSPs later on.

Comment: I would think that the web programming book would tell you this. Its very basic.

Comment: Its also easy to test. Make your doGet and doPost print different things, click the link, and see which one you get.

Comment: It doesn't, developerwjk. It skips on many aspects. And thank you, i didn't think about testing it that way at all.